# Get window name on Red Hat GNOME

Tags: linux, rhel, gnome, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to get the title of a window (e.g., gnome-terminal) via a terminal command, without installing any outside packages such as `xdotool`, `xprop` or `wmctrl`?

Much appreciated.

Comment: does something like xprop (ref: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133254) or this link from SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252906/how-to-get-the-list-of-open-windows-from-xserver) answer your question?

Comment: Isn't at least `xprop` available in a package in RHEL? How will you be specifying the terminal emulator: by its window ID, by clicking on it, by the terminal file (`/dev/pts/NUMBER`), or what?

Comment: `xprop` is not available on my RHEL machine. It's a work machine, so package installs are somewhat restricted.